# In MVC3, How can the controller know the result of the unobtrusive validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, controller

I'm using `C#`, `MVC3` and `VS2010`

I noticed that even though the valdiation results to false, the controller method still gets executed. This makes the validation useless on the server-side. Unless there is a way to get the result.

**---- EDITS -----**
Here is how i'm using it. Is it done properly? At least the validation messages show up, and the textbox turns red.

Model:

```
public class CategoriaModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Nome é obrigatório!")]
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "First Name max length is 10")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }



}
```

View:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Salvar", "Test", FormMethod.Post))
{


    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Nome)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Nome)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Nome)                           


    <input type="submit" value="Salvar" />
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Salvar(CategoriaModel catModel)
        {

            ViewBag.StatusMessage = "Ok!";



            return View("Index");
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

testing `ModelState.IsValid` property, however if client side validation fails the Action should not be called. Check if you're actually validating all your Model properties.

Comment: Well, pretty strange. Btw to track it down, you can just add a breakpoint in your controller. the watch the ModelState object, look at the two collections (Key, Values) and find who's the culprit of your Invalid Model. Testing the ModelState.IsValid will prevent your code execution, but it will be nice to understand why the form is still submitted.

Comment: Just did that. ModelState.IsValid is false. Well, testing it will solve my problem like you said, but would be nice for this to work properly.

Comment: ok, now you've got a fix, in order to understand who's at fault, inspect the ModelState.Keys and ModelState.Values collections, there should be an entry for the property invelidating the Model.

Comment: If do that i can know which properties are invalid. In my case there is only one property, so this is unnecessary (still i did it, no surprises there). You have any ideas why the controller is still getting called when client-validation fails?

Comment: Everything seems correct. I'm verifying things with default MVC 3 Project (the one with logon and user creation), and if the client side validation fails the form is not submitted. The only difference I see between your code and the sample is the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js inclusion. Try removing it or moving after the other validation js.